# Is there a way to use FtpWebRequest to authenticate to FTP using client certificates in C# which can work from iis also?

Tags: c#

I have tried with solution given by stackoverflow.

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.example.com");
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "");

// Query certificate from store

X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
const string tp = "2b6f8ac51a85cbaf429474a55304313968667611";
X509Certificate2 cert2 = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, tp, true)[0];
store.Close();    

FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.example.com");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "");

// Query certificate from store

X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
const string tp = "2b6f8ac51a85cbaf429474a55304313968667611";
X509Certificate2 cert2 = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, tp, true)[0];
store.Close();

// Add certificate into request
request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert2);
```

This works perfect for when run from console application. However i have deploy this in iis and run from iis following error occur.

```
An exception of type 'System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.
Inner exception:
{"An unknown error occurred while processing the certificate"}
at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object obj)
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.RequestCallback(Object obj)
   at System.Net.CommandStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()
   at System.Net.ConnectionPool.Destroy(PooledStream pooledStream)
   at System.Net.ConnectionPool.PutConnection(PooledStream pooledStream, Object owningObject, Int32 creationTimeout, Boolean canReuse)
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.FinishRequestStage(RequestStage stage)
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Demo.Controllers.HomeController.GetAndDownloadFTPFile()
   at Demo.Controllers.HomeController.Index()
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
```

Can anybody please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about everything else, however your IIS apppool probably wont have access to the certificate you think is in `StoreLocation.CurrentUser`

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
```

I.e my postulation is that it cant find the certificate

Comment: I have tried it by loading from certificate from specific location.

Comment: What line is it failing on

Answer (score 0):

My issue is resolved install p12 certificate with trusted certificate folder. Double click on p12 certification and install it with local user and at last browse folder and add into trusted folder. It works for me.